# What's wrong with my WPF Binding (in C# code)?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I didnt use WPF for a long time so I'm quite sure this is an easy question for most of you but here is my xaml code :

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar Name="Progress" Width="200" Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

and here is the C# code :

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _MyInt;
        public int MyInt
        {
            get { return _MyInt; }
            set
            {
                _MyInt = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyInt");
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyInt = 99;

            Random random = new Random();
            System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                MyInt = random.Next(0, 100);
            };
            aTimer.Interval = 500;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            Binding b = new Binding();
            b.Source = MyInt;
            b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            Progress.SetBinding(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, b);
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

When the application starts I got a 99 value on my ProgressBar so the binding seems to work but then, it doesn't refresh at all...

Comment: Progress.Value = MyInt; should do it no ?
I tried with an ItemSource of a ListBox and it worked

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368479/wpf-data-binding-with-code

Comment: I know I can do a Binding "manually" but can't I but it this way ? (like in my code snippet)

Comment: All your snippet is doing is assigning a value to the value of your control.  You need to explicitly set the binding for it to work (either in xaml or in the code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Progress.Value = MyInt` is simply setting the value to whatever the current value in `MyInt` is. This is not the same as binding the value, which means the value will point to `MyInt`, not be a copy of `MyInt`

To create a binding in the code-behind, it would look something like this:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = this;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("MyInt");
Progress.SetBinding(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, b);
```

An alternative is to just bind the value in your XAML and update it as needed:

```
<ProgressBar Name="Progress" Value="{Binding MyInt}" />
```

Then in the code behind: `MyInt = newValue;`

Comment: Code this strange error : Member System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase.ValueProperty' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne Sorry, the binding needs to reference the `ProgressBar` class, not your ProgressBar Instance. I updated my answer

Comment: I got this error with ur new version :
{"'The invocation of the constructor on type 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'."}

Comment: If I comment the line "Progress.SetBinding(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, myBinding);" I got no more error but the binding doesnt work ofc.. !

Comment: And I got the same error if I try to bind in the xaml file :( Dunno if this has to do with the Timer im using

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne I made another update. In most cases, I'd specify a `Path` in my binding but since you're binding directly to `MyInt`, the `Path` is not needed, and apparently bindings without a `Path` cannot be `TwoWay` (default). To get rid of the error, just set the Binding Mode to `OneWay`

Comment: Ok, I got no error with the OneWayBinding mode but the Binding doesn't work :/

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne Can you define "doesn't work"? You should only need to set the binding once, and then in your timer just set `MyInt = newValue` to update the value.

Comment: (updates the question with ur code so u can know exactly my whole code)

Comment: doesnt work means that my progressbar doesnt "move" at all. In theory it should randomly move from 0 to 100

Comment: If I set a value (MyInt = 98) before Timer.Elapsed then my ProgressBar is set to 98, so the binding kinda works but then, it doesn't refresh at all

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5502/discussion-between-guillaume-cogranne-and-rachel)

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne Hrrrmm for whatever reason it doesn't like binding without a Path. I've updated my answer again to bind the ProgressBar to the current item, then set the `Path` to `MyInt`. I'm not actually sure why it won't bind directly to `MyInt`, however the code posted works.

Comment: humm by the way, dyou know the equivalent of ProgressBar.ValueProperty for ListBox.ItemSource ?

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne In most cases it is `[ClassName].[PropertyName]Property`, so `ListBox.ItemsSource` would be `ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty`

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne It should work.... `MyListBox.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);`

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think your window should be implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
You are putting the data in your Window. You should have a separate class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and then set it as a DataContext to your Window. After that you need to add a Binding either through code, or in XAml like this :

```
<ProgressBar Name="Progress" Width="200" Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Margin="10" Value="67" Value="{Binding MyInt}"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the necessity of INotifyPropertyChanged but the thing is that I'd like to code the binding in C# code (not xaml) !

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is typically used on the view model not on a view.  Since you have code in your view code-behind, that doesn't really fit the architecture you're using.

Comment: Rachel posted the code needed to create Binding in C#. BUt you still need to INotifyPropertyChanged, since WPF can't know when you values change, unless it checks it everytime, very suboptimal, we need to let it know that something changed.

Comment: @mydogisbox even if it is in the Window, WPF has no way to know that the values changed, unless he calls  Progress.Value = MyInt; everytime MyInt changes

Comment: and it that case Binding is useless

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I always do this with dependency properties rather than simply properties.

Comment: I was using DependencyProperties, but than I realized that they are heavier than simply using INotifyPropertyChanged. Dependency properties should be used whehn you write your own UserControls. However they do the job:)

Comment: I'm almost exclusively writing my own controls at this point.  Doing some prep work for a large project.

Comment: I edited massively my question, does one of you got an idea about the "new" problem ? -_-