# How can I create a binding in code-behind that doesn't specify a Path?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I was answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8343085/302677) about creating a binding in code-behind, and my original attempt at answering it was to post binding code that didn't specify a `Path`. This binding compiles fine, however the value is never updated. If I change the binding to use a Path, it works fine.

Why is this? And what is the correct way to create a binding in code-behind that doesn't have a Path? For example, how would I recreate `Value="{Binding }"` in code-behind?

Non-Working code:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = SomeInt;
b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
MyProgressBar.SetBinding(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, b);

SomeInt = 50;
```

Working code:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = this;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("SomeInt");
MyProgressBar.SetBinding(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, b);

SomeInt = 50;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binding engine subscribes to [INPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and [DP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx)-changes on the `Source` object (and non-leaves on the `Path`), and checks whether the `Path` property/properties was/were changed. If there is no `Path` there are no notifications. A rather unfortunate drawback.

*(I might be oversimplifying the system a bit but the essence is that there are no updates to source-changes, they are not and cannot be monitored)*

---

`{Binding}` is equivalent to `new Binding()` (no additional properties), this binding may update as there are events for `DataContext` changes.

Comment: That's probably true too: `INPC` says which *property* changed. There's no mechanism to say "the whole *object* changed".

Comment: @JoeWhite However I can set my binding to nothing (`{Binding }`), and the `PropertyChange` notification works just fine. Isn't there a way to do that in code-behind?

Comment: @Rachel: That is because there are notifications for the DataContext changes, that is an exception to the rule though.

Comment: @H.B. Could you suggest the code-behind syntax which would be the equivalent to `{Binding }`?

Comment: @Rachel: That's just `new Binding()`, no source no path, nothing else.

Comment: @H.B. But that doesn't seem to update the value when it changes. If I set DataContext='MyInt'; and bind the Value property to a `new Binding()` the initial value loads but the changes don't.

Comment: @H.B. Nevermind, I need to bind the `DataContext`, not set it, so that it responds to PropertyChange notifications. Thanks :)

Comment: @Rachel: You're welcome, also feel free to make any additions to my answer which you think might be useful.

Comment: I've been doing my code-behind bindings without the Path, but in my current problem, adding Path solved the issue. (FYI the problem: (all in code-behind) Canvas children must resize with canvas parent (same size). `Binding bindingW = new Binding(); bindingW.Source = this; bindingW.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth"); this.CanvasChildren.SetBinding(Canvas.WidthProperty, bindingW);` The same for the height and it's done (this is the CanvasParent)!

Answer (score 1):

[`Binding.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx) is typed as `System.Object`. So when you do:

```
b.Source = SomeInt;
```

you're assigning a value type (`System.Int32`) into something of type `System.Object`, which means you'll get a boxed copy of the original value.

The boxed copy lives on the heap and has no relation to the original variable. When you modify the original variable, nothing happens to the boxed copy.