# How to convert a "xaml string" template to a compilable xaml/control

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

This is my existing "Xaml string" template stored in a Resource file.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn 
DataMemberBinding="{Binding <<PropertyName>>}"         
IsReadOnlyBinding="{Binding Is<<PropertyName>>ReadOnly}">   
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  >
                <!--some more markup with similar bindings here-->
            </StackPanel  >
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

In the code behind, I use the XamlReader to create the markup for the column and latter add it to the Grid.

```
var xamlTemplate = Properties.Resources.GridColumnTemplate.Replace( "<<PropertyName>>", "MyProperty");
var col = ( GridViewDataColumn )XamlReader.Load( xamlTemplate );
detailsGrid.Columns.Add( col );
```

Now, I need to replace this with a compilable Xaml/Control instead.
Is there a way to do it?

I have thought of extensively using converters and binding to the Context of MyProperty, but that doesn't sound like a good solution.

Comment: I believe you could put that XAML into a control and remove the bindings, and then create a new instance for each column and programmatically add the bindings. This isn't really very clean though, a cleaner way would be to make this more self-contained like a user control with its own dependency properties which you would reference internally and then wire up declaratively (or programmatically, as you appear to be doing).

Comment: Thanks. I am already trying to create a control with dependency properties, but not sure how do I go about creating the dependency properties on the fly..
Eg: I have a collection of properties: "MyProperty1", "MyProperty2"..

My current code would generate 2 columns for each of these with the respective bindings, how do I achieve the same with the user control?

Comment: You shouldn't need to create any dependency properties on the fly - you would basically be deriving from the telerik GridViewDataColumn to make a new class and then creating instances of those to add to the grid. I was thinking of creating this as a control (with it's own XAML and code-behind) to hold the two new dependency properties, called something like DataMember and IsReadOnly, which makes it easier to setup when you're creating instances of it to add to your grid, but is really just abstracting the complexity of whatever XAML is within the control.

Comment: I am unsure whether I completely understand what you are trying to explain but wouldn't that still require me to Bind the MyProperties in the code behind, as I loop through my collection of properties?

Can you point me to an example, if any.

Comment: Yes, that's right - I posted an answer that includes a link to an example showing how to perform the binding in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be:

- derive your own column control (from the telerik one) with its own dependency properties
- loop through your collection of properties:

  - create an instance of your column control
  - set the bindings [in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368479/wpf-data-binding-with-code)

Comment: Could not create a templated control out of the Column but instead decided to create one out of the Grid and bind in the code behind for each property.